# GoogleAPI/JSON: Retrieving data from spreadsheet?

Tags: javascript, spreadsheet, google-docs

It turns out that I came up with my own solution:

```
var data = {"version":"1.0","encoding":"UTF-8","feed":{"xmlns":"http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom","xmlns$openSearch":"http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearchrss/1.0/","xmlns$gs":"http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006","xmlns$batch":"http://schemas.google.com/gdata/batch","id":{"$t":"https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/0ArzGbN1Jn061dFdJZ29VcWttZExoRXQ5TnZVX29xUlE/od6/public/basic"},"updated":{"$t":"2012-10-11T21:56:33.189Z"},"category":[{"scheme":"http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006","term":"http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006#cell"}],"title":{"type":"text","$t":"Sheet1"},"link":[{"rel":"alternate","type":"text/html","href":"https://spreadsheets.google.com/pub?key\u003d0ArzGbN1Jn061dFdJZ29VcWttZExoRXQ5TnZVX29xUlE"},{"rel":"http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#feed","type":"application/atom+xml","href":"http://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/0ArzGbN1Jn061dFdJZ29VcWttZExoRXQ5TnZVX29xUlE/od6/public/basic"},{"rel":"http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#batch","type":"application/atom+xml","href":"http://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/0ArzGbN1Jn061dFdJZ29VcWttZExoRXQ5TnZVX29xUlE/od6/public/basic/batch"},{"rel":"self","type":"application/atom+xml","href":"http://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/0ArzGbN1Jn061dFdJZ29VcWttZExoRXQ5TnZVX29xUlE/od6/public/basic?alt\u003djson-in-script"}],"author":[{"name":{"$t":"dhuanco"},"email":{"$t":"dhuanco@gmail.com"}}],"openSearch$totalResults":{"$t":"9"},"openSearch$startIndex":{"$t":"1"},"entry":[{"id":{"$t":"https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/0ArzGbN1Jn061dFdJZ29VcWttZExoRXQ5TnZVX29xUlE/od6/public/basic/R1C1"},"updated":{"$t":"2012-10-11T21:56:33.189Z"},"category":[{"scheme":"http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006","term":"http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006#cell"}],"title":{"type":"text","$t":"A1"},"content":{"type":"text","$t":"Maria"},"link":[{"rel":"self","type":"application/atom+xml","href":"http://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/0ArzGbN1Jn061dFdJZ29VcWttZExoRXQ5TnZVX29xUlE/od6/public/basic/R1C1"}]},{"id":{"$t":"https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/0ArzGbN1Jn061dFdJZ29VcWttZExoRXQ5TnZVX29xUlE/od6/public/basic/R1C2"},"updated":{"$t":"2012-10-11T21:56:33.189Z"},"category":[{"scheme":"http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006","term":"http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006#cell"}],"title":{"type":"text","$t":"B1"},"content":{"type":"text","$t":"30"},"link":[{"rel":"self","type":"application/atom+xml","href":"http://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/0ArzGbN1Jn061dFdJZ29VcWttZExoRXQ5TnZVX29xUlE/od6/public/basic/R1C2"}]},{"id":{"$t":"https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/0ArzGbN1Jn061dFdJZ29VcWttZExoRXQ5TnZVX29xUlE/od6/public/basic/R1C3"},"updated":{"$t":"2012-10-11T21:56:33.189Z"},"category":[{"scheme":"http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006","term":"http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006#cell"}],"title":{"type":"text","$t":"C1"},"content":{"type":"text","$t":"USA"},"link":[{"rel":"self","type":"application/atom+xml","href":"http://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/0ArzGbN1Jn061dFdJZ29VcWttZExoRXQ5TnZVX29xUlE/od6/public/basic/R1C3"}]},{"id":{"$t":"https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/0ArzGbN1Jn061dFdJZ29VcWttZExoRXQ5TnZVX29xUlE/od6/public/basic/R2C1"},"updated":{"$t":"2012-10-11T21:56:33.189Z"},"category":[{"scheme":"http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006","term":"http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006#cell"}],"title":{"type":"text","$t":"A2"},"content":{"type":"text","$t":"John"},"link":[{"rel":"self","type":"application/atom+xml","href":"http://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/0ArzGbN1Jn061dFdJZ29VcWttZExoRXQ5TnZVX29xUlE/od6/public/basic/R2C1"}]},{"id":{"$t":"https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/0ArzGbN1Jn061dFdJZ29VcWttZExoRXQ5TnZVX29xUlE/od6/public/basic/R2C2"},"updated":{"$t":"2012-10-11T21:56:33.189Z"},"category":[{"scheme":"http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006","term":"http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006#cell"}],"title":{"type":"text","$t":"B2"},"content":{"type":"text","$t":"32"},"link":[{"rel":"self","type":"application/atom+xml","href":"http://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/0ArzGbN1Jn061dFdJZ29VcWttZExoRXQ5TnZVX29xUlE/od6/public/basic/R2C2"}]},{"id":{"$t":"https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/0ArzGbN1Jn061dFdJZ29VcWttZExoRXQ5TnZVX29xUlE/od6/public/basic/R2C3"},"updated":{"$t":"2012-10-11T21:56:33.189Z"},"category":[{"scheme":"http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006","term":"http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006#cell"}],"title":{"type":"text","$t":"C2"},"content":{"type":"text","$t":"ENG"},"link":[{"rel":"self","type":"application/atom+xml","href":"http://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/0ArzGbN1Jn061dFdJZ29VcWttZExoRXQ5TnZVX29xUlE/od6/public/basic/R2C3"}]},{"id":{"$t":"https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/0ArzGbN1Jn061dFdJZ29VcWttZExoRXQ5TnZVX29xUlE/od6/public/basic/R3C1"},"updated":{"$t":"2012-10-11T21:56:33.189Z"},"category":[{"scheme":"http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006","term":"http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006#cell"}],"title":{"type":"text","$t":"A3"},"content":{"type":"text","$t":"Susan"},"link":[{"rel":"self","type":"application/atom+xml","href":"http://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/0ArzGbN1Jn061dFdJZ29VcWttZExoRXQ5TnZVX29xUlE/od6/public/basic/R3C1"}]},{"id":{"$t":"https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/0ArzGbN1Jn061dFdJZ29VcWttZExoRXQ5TnZVX29xUlE/od6/public/basic/R3C2"},"updated":{"$t":"2012-10-11T21:56:33.189Z"},"category":[{"scheme":"http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006","term":"http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006#cell"}],"title":{"type":"text","$t":"B3"},"content":{"type":"text","$t":"25"},"link":[{"rel":"self","type":"application/atom+xml","href":"http://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/0ArzGbN1Jn061dFdJZ29VcWttZExoRXQ5TnZVX29xUlE/od6/public/basic/R3C2"}]},{"id":{"$t":"https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/0ArzGbN1Jn061dFdJZ29VcWttZExoRXQ5TnZVX29xUlE/od6/public/basic/R3C3"},"updated":{"$t":"2012-10-11T21:56:33.189Z"},"category":[{"scheme":"http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006","term":"http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006#cell"}],"title":{"type":"text","$t":"C3"},"content":{"type":"text","$t":"GER"},"link":[{"rel":"self","type":"application/atom+xml","href":"http://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/0ArzGbN1Jn061dFdJZ29VcWttZExoRXQ5TnZVX29xUlE/od6/public/basic/R3C3"}]}]}};

function format_ss(data){ // format spreadsheet
    var table = new Array();

    for(var k in data.feed.entry){
        var id = data.feed.entry[k].id.$t;
        var row = id.match(/R([0-9]*)C/)[1]-1;
        var col = id.match(/C([0-9]*)/)[1]-1;

        if(Object.prototype.toString.call(table[row]) != '[object Array]')
            table[row] = new Array();

        table[row][col] = data.feed.entry[k].content.$t;
    }

    return table;
}

var ss = format_ss(data);
```

It worked like a charm.

Original Question:

This is a public spreadsheet I created using google docs:

> https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?key=0ArzGbN1Jn061dFdJZ29VcWttZExoRXQ5TnZVX29xUlE&output=html

My problem is, how can I properly get this data with JSON?

I tried

> http://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/0ArzGbN1Jn061dFdJZ29VcWttZExoRXQ5TnZVX29xUlE/od6/public/basic?alt=json-in-script&callback=test

This is awful to work with. The json data doesn't come properly formatted, for example I can't exactly tell what cell belongs to which column/field.

Does anyone know a better way to fetch this spreadsheet data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look under the "Entry" section you'll see:

`"id": {
"$t": "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/0ArzGbN1Jn061dFdJZ29VcWttZExoRXQ5TnZVX29xUlE/od6/public/basic/R1C1"
}`

The ID is basically the URL of Row 1, Column 1.  Then under that you'll find the:
`"content": {
"type": "text",
"$t": "Maria"
}`

The $t value there should give you your data.  I have to agree it's a bit verbose but that's the nature of something that has so many properties.

Comment: Yeah. But the big problem is, this spreadsheet contains 3 rows, each containing 3 cells. So the 'entry' array contains 9 elements, each representing a single cell. But how can I tell which row a cell belongs to if there's no order for this array?

Comment: You'll need to iterate through the "Entry" collection and find the "ID" element.  The $t value ends in R1C1, R1C2, etc. that will tell you what cell you're looking at Row 1 Column 1, Row 1 Column 2, etc.  Based upon that you'll have to get the $t value in the "content" collection.  It's basically XML that's been converted to JSON so you sort of have to think in XPATH mode.

Comment: so in order to know where a cell belongs to, i have to do some string manipulation on the 'id' element... why couldn't they make things simple, something like: feed.row[1].col[3]

Comment: It looks to me like the JavaScript API was a bit of an afterthought by Google. Maybe it will get a little better in version 3.1 or 4, if they're working on that.

Comment: You can change the FEED type to `list` instead of `cells` (see [the docs](https://developers.google.com/gdata/samples/spreadsheet_sample)). For example: [https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/0ArzGbN1Jn061dFdJZ29VcWttZExoRXQ5TnZVX29xUlE/od6/public/basic?alt=json-in-script](https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/0ArzGbN1Jn061dFdJZ29VcWttZExoRXQ5TnZVX29xUlE/od6/public/basic?alt=json-in-script)